# Input desde un teclado virtual y que se dibujen los caracteres pulsados en pantalla usando Java graphics

Tags: java

Quiero hacer un Wordle para un proyecto de clase y me gustaría poder coger los caracteres del teclado virtual y al ir pulsándolos rellenar cada fila hasta cinco caracteres.

El problema que tengo es que no sé como hacerlo para que al pulsar el botón se me dibuje un caracter tras otro, ya que solo se me redibuja el mismo caracter pero se va moviendo de posición.

Adjunto mi código por si alguien puede echarme un cable, soy muy principiante así que espero que me entendáis.

Gracias.

```
    public void paint(Graphics wordle) {
        super.paint(wordle);

        // TITULO Y FONDO
        wordle.setColor(COLOR_FONDO_TITULO);
        wordle.fillRect(273, 69, 230, 40);
        wordle.setColor(COLOR_SEPARACION);
        wordle.fillRect(315, 69, 5, 40);
        wordle.fillRect(355, 69, 5, 40);
        wordle.fillRect(392, 69, 5, 40);
        wordle.fillRect(430, 69, 5, 40);
        wordle.fillRect(462, 69, 5, 40);
        wordle.setColor(COLOR_INT_LETRAS);
        wordle.setFont(FUENTE_INT_LETRAS);
        wordle.drawString("W  O  R  D  L  E", 280, 100);
        wordle.setColor(COLOR_FRASE_TITULO);
        wordle.setFont(FUENTE_FRASE);
        wordle.drawString("El juego de palabras diario", 318, 128);

        // FILAS
        for (int i = 195; i <= 375; i = i + 45) {
            for (int j = 280; j <= 520; j = j + 50) {
                wordle.setColor(COLOR_CAJONES);
                wordle.fillRect(j - 10, i - 20, 40, 40);
            }
        }
        
        //ESCRIBIR
        if(escribir==1) {
            while(i<5) {
                if(escribir==1) {
                    escribir=0;
                    wordle.setFont(FUENTE_INT_LETRAS);
                    wordle.setColor(COLOR_INT_LETRAS);
                    wordle.drawString(tecla, x, y);
                    x=x+50;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
}
    
    public void cargarLetras(){
        for (int i = 0; i <= letras.length - 1; i++) {
            botones[i] = new JButton();
            botones[i].setText(letras[i]);
            botones[i].addActionListener(this);
            jpnPanel.add(botones[i]);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= letras.length - 3; i++) {
            if (e.getSource()==botones[i]) {
                tecla=letras[i];
                escribir=1;
                repaint();
            }
        }
        if(e.getSource()==botones[26]) {
            
        }
        if(e.getSource()==botones[27]) {
            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo algunos problemines en tu código...

```
if( escribir == 1 ) {   // si escribir es "1" entro al cuerpo

    while( i < 5) {  // mientras "i" sea menor que "5", itero

        if( escribir == 1 ) {  // repito condición
            escribir = 0;  // al tener la condición anterior, solo entrará una vez en el segundo if

            wordle.setFont( FUENTE_INT_LETRAS );
            wordle.setColor( COLOR_INT_LETRAS );
            wordle.drawString( tecla, x, y );  // siempre va a imprimir lo mismo, creo que deberías usar "tecla[ i ];", y modificar lo necesario en "actionPerformed"
            x = x + 50;

              // el "break" se asegura que no haya una segunda iteración
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Una posible correción sería la siguiente}:

```
if( escribir == 1 ) {   
    while( i < 5) {  
        escribir = 0;  
        wordle.setFont( FUENTE_INT_LETRAS );
        wordle.setColor( COLOR_INT_LETRAS );
        wordle.drawString( tecla[ i ], x, y );  
        x = x + 50;          
        i++;
    }
}

public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    for( int i = 0; i <= letras.length - 3; i++ ) {
        if( e.getSource() == botones[i] ) {
            tecla[ i ] = letras[i];
            escribir = 1;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    if( e.getSource() == botones[26] ) {        }
    if( e.getSource() == botones[27] ) {        }
}
```